# Ionic 2 - Side menu not showing on duplicate page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app in which a user can go from home -> 'topic view' (which contains a back button to home and a side menu like so:)

```
<ion-menu id="itemHierarchy-{{_pageId}}" side="right" persistent="true" [content]="content">
    //toolbar stuff
</ion-menu>

<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button right menuToggle="itemHierarchy-{{_pageId}}">
      <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        <ion-title>name</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content #topicView padding>
</ion-content>
```

I have a link in the 'topic-view' page which navigates to another 'topic-view' page (pushes it onto the stack via deeplinker), and in it the new side menu doesn't open. I presume this is because there are two 'topicView' 'ion-content' nodes in the stack, but these cant be assigned a dynamic ID so not sure how to fix it... anyone?

Comment: For anyone else wanting to know how to solve this - I put the menu and its contents in app.html and created a service which kept track of which page was opened and thus updated the contents of the nav, and observables in app.component listened for changes